# WSO2 Logout ID token signature validation failed

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to logout from my service provider saas registered in wso2.
I'm login with tenant user es. tenant@domain.com;
When I make the logout request "https://:9443/oidc/logout?id_token_hint=&post_logout_redirect_uri=" it response with this error:
"ID token signature validation failed."
I've check "Use tenant domain in local subject identifier" option in service provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's couple of things that could've gone wrong here. First, the entered id_token_hint param could be expired or invalid. How did you obtain the IDToken in this case?

Second, have you registered the post_logout_redirect_uri in the SP configurations in the IdP? Follow this to verify if the post_logout_redirect_uri is configured properly in the IdP. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/openid-connect-logout-url-redirection/